# Django render html with jinja tag in template

Tags: django, templates, jinja2

I have some little problem. I have site and all content save in database. What could I write in src image tag which save in my database with other HTML text to load images from static folder. For example:`<p>Some text</p>
<img src="???">
<p>Another text text</p>`. This is the date which is in my database field called 'text'. On main page it load without any problem. But when I go to another page URL variable change from

> http: //127.0.0.1:8000/

to

> http: //127.0.0.1:8000/page/

and if I wrote in src attribute in database field

> 'static/img/1.png'

image URL on HTML page become

> http: //127.0.0.1:8000/page/static/img/1.png

and image don't load. How could I write or what could I change on my project to fix that?

Comment: try with /static/img/1.png  add slash ('/') before static in src attribute.

Comment: Yeah! It's works! =) Thank KuMaR!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ('/') before static  in src of image attribute from database

```
/static/img/1.png
```

because we use STATIC_URL = '/static/'  in django settings.py